# Why is  the Breusch-Pagan test significant on simulated data designed not to be heteroscedastic?

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity

I'm testing the residuals of a linear regression using **Breusch-Pagan** Test to detect Heteroscedasticity.

This is the plot of the residuals:
[image: Residuals]

and this is the R code:

```
> library(lmtest)
> 
> mod <- lm(rnorm(1000)~1)
> 
> bptest(mod)

    studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  mod 
BP = 0, df = 0, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Could someone tell me why it rejects the null hypothesis of homoscedastic errors?

The plot doesn't look heteroscedastic.

**EDIT:**

However the plot is an example, I have two list of prices (**priceA** and **priceB**), I need to check if the residuals generated by a linear regression of these two list: lm(priceA ~ priceB + 0) I need zero intercept are homescedastic or not. Could someone give me a small example? The length of each price list is 750.

**EDIT:**

I also get:

BP = 67.4362, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16

with this chart
[image: new charts]

Does it be homoscedastic? I have plotted the residuals.

**@Wolfgang**, I get this result following the example you posted.

```
> summary(mod)$r.squared * 750
[1] 681.0114
```

Comment: Unless the index is some *meaningful quantity* (e.g., directly related to a time variable), this plot doesn't tell you very much. You might start by looking at a plot of the residuals versus the fitted values.

Comment: @cardinal I need a method to check if my residuals are homo/hetero scedastic. My goal is not to see the result plotting something. I plot the chart above because I get a strange p.value, but I Only need a response if the model is homoscedastic. Could this method good for me? i have a matrix with prices so i do: lm(prices[,1] ~ prices[,2]+0) I need zero intercept....if I put +0 I always get p-value < 2.2e-16

Comment: Why do you want the intercept to be 0?

Comment: @Wolfgang, because if one stock ir rising +2 also the other should be the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really understanding your reasoning there. If you want to examine whether the variance in the residuals (when regressing `prices[,1]` on `prices[,2]`) changes as a function of `prices[,2]`, then I would suggest you do `bptest(lm(prices[,1] ~ prices[,2]))`.

Comment: Is that a plot of the residuals from the model `lm(prices[,1] ~ prices[,2])`? In that case, you do not need any test to tell you that the residuals do not look like they are supposed to look. They should scatter randomly around 0 with no apparent pattern. They clearly do not. There is strong autocorrelation in those residuals. I would say heteroscedasticity is the least of your problems.

Comment: @Wolfgang, YES, lm(prices[,1] ~ prices[,2])  do you think I have to use another test to check the "autocorrelation" instead of IF the residuals are homoscedastic/heteroscedastic? IN this case what method do you advice me? Obviously I have to do it programmatically so i can't check each chart visually. Autocorrelation checks should be good for me?

Comment: You don't need to test for autocorrelation. It is obvious from the plot that there is autocorrelation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, the data are not heteroscedastic (by way of how you simulated them). Did you notice the 0 degrees of freedom of the test? That is a hint that something is going wrong here. The B-P test takes the squared residuals from the model and tests whether the predictors in the model (or any other predictors you specify) can account for substantial amounts of variability in these values. Since you only have the intercept in the model, it cannot account for any variability by definition.

Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch-Pagan_test

Also, make sure you read `help(bptest)`. That should help to clarify things.

One thing that is going wrong here is that the `bptest()` function apparently does not test for this errant case and happens to throw out a tiny p-value. In fact, if you look carefully at the code underlying the `bptest()` function, essentially this is happening:

```
format.pval(pchisq(0,0), digits=4)
```

which gives `"< 2.2e-16"`. So, `pchisq(0,0)` returns `0` and that is turned into `"< 2.2e-16"` by `format.pval()`. In a way, that is all correct, but it would probably help to test for zero dfs in `bptest()` to avoid this sort of confusion.

**EDIT**

There is still lots of confusion concerning this question. Maybe it helps to really show what the B-P test actually does. Here is an example. First, let's simulate some data that are homoscedastic. Then we fit a regression model with two predictors. And then we carry out the B-P test with the `bptest()` function.

```
library(lmtest)
n <- 100    
x1i <- rnorm(n)
x2i <- rnorm(n)
yi  <- rnorm(n)
mod <- lm(yi ~ x1i + x2i)
bptest(mod)
```

So, what is really happening? First, take the squared residuals based on the regression model. Then take $n \times R^2$ when regressing these squared residuals on the predictors that were included in the original model (note that the `bptest()` function uses the same predictors as in the original model, but one can also use other predictors here if one suspects that the heteroscedasticity is a function of other variables). That is the test statistic for the B-P test. Under the null hypothesis of homoscedasticity, this test statistic follows a chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the number of predictors used in the test (not counting the intercept). So, let's see if we can get the same results:

```
e2 <- resid(mod)^2
bp <- summary(lm(e2 ~ x1i + x2i))$r.squared * n
bp
pchisq(bp, df=2, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

Yep, that works. By chance, the test above may turn out to be significant (which is a Type I error since the data simulated are homoscedastic), but in most cases it will be non-significant.

Comment: I'm consufed at the moment. I have two vectors with many prices (stock prices). Can I test if their residuals are constant with this method or not? could you give me a small example? thank you so much!

Comment: When the variance in the residuals is heteroscedastic, it means that the variance changes as a function of one of the predictor variables, as a function of some other variable not included in the model, and/or it changes over time. For example, as Karl already pointed out, you could use the index of the observations as an explanatory variable to test whether the variance changes over time.

Comment: with index do you mean a vector like: c(1:N) where N is the length of my residuals vector?

Comment: Yes. Like Karl showed.

Comment: :Wolfgang BP tests the hypthesis that all the "information" has been extracted from the predictors. That is a far cry from thoroughly testing for non-constant variance as non-constant variance can arise from a number of sources. Please see my comment at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/how-to-check-if-the-volatility-is-stationary

Comment: @IrishStat If the test is significant, then this suggests heteroscedasticity as a function of the predictors used for the test. That's all that the test is doing. The actual reasons for the heteroscedasticity is another issue. It may be the case that the variance in the errors is really changing, but it could, for example, also be due to omitted predictors.

Comment: @Wolfgang if i use bptest(lm(prices[,1] ~ prices[,2])) I continue to get: BP = 67.4362, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16, take a look at the new chart above.

Answer (score 4):

The results are not meaningful without some predictor (note `df=0`).  *Heteroscedastic* means that the variance is not constant, but not constant with respect to *what*?  Perhaps you have in mind the index (order of measurement)?  Then you should do

```
y <- rnorm(1000)
x <- 1:1000
mod <- lm(y~x)
bptest(mod) # I get p=0.59
```

If you just have a vector of numbers, there's not a whole lot of meaning to the question "Is the variance constant?"  For example, consider a mixture of two normal distributions with different variances:

```
v <- sample(c(1,10), 100, repl=TRUE)
y <- rnorm(100, 0, v)
```

$\text{var}(y|v)$ is not constant, but depends on $v$.  But unconditionally, $\text{var}(y)$ is just a number.

Comment: what are the y elements?

Comment: I was following from your example; edited to be more clear

Comment: the last example seems constant, I get: BP = 0.0133, df = 1, p-value = 0.9083

Comment: however as I told, I need this test to check the residuals generated from a regression with two list of prices lm(pricesA~PricesB) How can I use this method to check their residuals?

Comment: what about if i do: newMod <- lm(resid(mod)~c(1,750)) where 750 are the length of the vector of prices. Then, I tried lm(resid(mod)~rep(1,750)) I always get a p-value = 1 surelly is a stupid questione but, could you explain the reason? Thank you so much!

Comment: For the model `mod <- lm(pricesA ~ PricesB)`, I think you want just `bptest(pricesA ~ PricesB)`.

Comment: hmmm, in this case i have: 
 studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  prices[, 1] ~ prices[, 2] 
BP = 67.4362, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16

Comment: otherwise If I test: bptest(resid(mod)~c(1:750)) i get: studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  resid(mod) ~ c(1:750) 
BP = 2.0368, df = 1, p-value = 0.1535 that is correct because  I have done the test on a model that is surelly homoscedastic. So now only the test with the "index" seems to work well

Comment: Karl, If i use the "index" on the model that has the residuals I plot above I get 2.2e-16 that is correct because the data is heteroscedastic... so now, How to use it correctly? with or without the index?

Comment: @Dail The B-P test takes the *squared* residuals for the regression. I updated my answer to provide more details and to really show what is happening. Hopefully, this will clarify things for you.

Answer (score 0):

:Dail To test for non-constant variance one must understand the hypothesis behind the popular statistical tests. you need to follow the recipe i,e, the tests that I outlined in [How to check if the volatility is stationary?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/how-to-check-if-the-volatility-is-stationary)
to fully verify that a series can't be proven to have non-constant variance. All six of the tests that I outlined must yield acceptance of the null hypothesis of non-constant variance. Rejection by any one of the 6 tests suggests that the error variance is indeed non-constant.